# float is not expanding a coordinately

Tags: css

I have this css code but float isn't happening in the left side columns, my table keep growing in the center of the page. And the left side columns is not expanding accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/14/

**my css code**

```
.container2 {
float:left;
width:15%;
background:#FFA500;
position:relative;
right:-0%;


}

.col1 {
float:left;
width:26%;
position:relative;
left:20%;
overflow:hidden;
height:570px;
bottom:-60px;


.footer {
        border:1px solid orange;
        position: relative;
        padding:0px;
        margin-top:-5px;
    font-size:15px;


    }
```

**my html code**

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">

<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Wellcome To Balhalfe Services Customer Reports</h1>
</div>

<div class="container2 ">


<div class="col1">
lililililili<br />
</div>

</div>


<div align="center">
        <H2 align="center"> Report Table</H></div> 

<table border="1" align="center"class="tableClass"> 
        <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>Download</b></td>
            </tr>

 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>eu contres.txt</td>
                <td>text/plain</td>
                <td>546</td>
                <td>2013-08-22 00:06:55</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=4&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>


  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

    <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

   <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?  id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

   <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

  <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr> </table>



<div class="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © balhalfe services 20103-2014</div>
```

Comment: sorry you can check it now.http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/14/

Comment: i'd do something like this: add a container with a background, give it a overflow:auto http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/14/

Comment: @jbenjohnson, can you show me in http://jsfiddle.net/ how to do it ? please

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You have an explicit width set on the sidebar. Why would you expect it to change sizes based on content?

Comment: oops here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E8jd3/18/

Comment: @isherwood, left side bar it have to expand to how many table added.

Comment: @jbenjohnson, if i change width:25%; in col1 its coming from other side. how to change the width:25%; with out coming from left side the page.

Comment: you want col1 to be on the right side of the table? the easiest was is to just change the float direction from left to right.

Comment: no i want it to be in left side. but the problem when changing the width size in col1 its coming from left side of the page. please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a "main" container and give it a property display

```
.main {
  height:auto;
  display:table;
}
```

and the divs inside

```
.container1 {
  display:table-cell;
  width:15%;
}
.container2 {
  display:table-cell;
  width:85%;
}
```

**Edit**

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/E8jd3/69/

Comment: review the link again the table is now aligned.

Comment: hi it's in the center of his container, what you really want? upload an image and the issue of your question of the left sidebar is resolved

Comment: no im not trying to upload image. every thing is prefect but the table isn't in the center of the page.please check it in your browser. the table have to be in the center of the page. and thank you for your effort with me.

Comment: what i need to push the table little more to the center of the page, can this be done ?

Comment: yes this can be done changin the margin of the .container2 table

Comment: if i change margin  of container2 the table keep coming down. yes it moving but till down. please look into it. what i want with same size moving the table to the center of the page.

Comment: change the second value of margin not the first "margin: 0 10px" keep the first with "0"