# CSS table not coming in center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS code with an HTML table. The problem the table is not coming in the center of the page.
I'm using *float* to expand left side bar, more table I add more expanding will happen to left side bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/39/

**My CSS code:**

```
.container2 {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    background: #FFA500;
    position: relative;
    right: -0%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 26%;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 570px;
    bottom: -60px;
    overflow: hidden;

.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    background: #fff;
}


.footer {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

**My HTML code:**

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Wellcome To Balhalfe Services Customer Reports</h1>
</div>
<div class="container2 ">
    <div class="col1">
        lililililili<br />
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div align="center">
            <H2 align="center">
            Report Table</H>
        </div>
        <table border="1" align="center"class="tableClass">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>Download</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>eu contres.txt</td>
                <td>text/plain</td>
                <td>546</td>
                <td>2013-08-22 00:06:55</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=4&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
    Copyright © balhalfe services 20103-2014
</div>
```

Comment: `align="center"` is deprecated (validation should have caught this).

Comment: I've corrected your indentation. As you can see, you forgot to close the .col1 class in CSS. Also, you're using single quotes `'` in HTML, you should use double quotes `"`. This may fix some of your issues. By the way, there is **no need** to give us such a large piece of HTML when all table rows are exacly the same. Also, use `&amp;` for `&` in your HTML.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers Thank you for not correcting the syntax errors in the code in your edit; they may be pivotal in correcting OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to paste a `div` around the table with this CSS code:

```
.center2 { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Reference here: [Table centering using CSS or HTML](http://theodorakis.net/tablecentertest.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I got your idea correct, you need to place the `<div class="col2">` outside of your `container2`.

Here is the edited fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8jd3/42/)

Comment: left side bar isn't expanding.. please check it

Comment: Sorry, i did not got your idea first. In that case simply remove the fixed width for the container2 in your original code. Because at the moment you set your total width to only 15% of the window.

Answer (score 0):

It was missing some close tags from

```
</div>
```

Chek this http://jsfiddle.net/E8jd3/62/ i also solved your problem of the left column, don't use float if you want to take all height with the dynamic table. It was resolved it in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19413508/2887133.

Comment: It's not missing a `</div>`. It's missing a correct closing tag for `<H2>`, though, which he wrote as `</H>`.